# How to make one checkbox to be unchecked at a time using angular2

Tags: angular

i have 3 checkboxes which are checked already. Now, if i uncheck one checkbox among 3, rest 2 checkboxes should be disabled with checked mark. When i again check the one which is unchecked then all 3 boxes should be enabled with checked.

HTML:

```html
    <div *ngFor="let contact of userList" [hidden]="!contact.isDisabled">

                  <input  type="checkbox" name="radio" (click)="selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, false)"
                    [(ngModel)]="contact.isChecked"  />
                  <a>{{ contact.FirstName }} &nbsp;{{ contact.LastName }}</a>
                </div>
```

TS:

```js
    selectCheckboxInvitee(evt, contact, isMultiple) {
        if (evt) {

          if (!isMultiple) {
            this.userList.forEach(function (obj) {
              if(!obj.isDisabled) {
              if (obj.Id === contact.Id) {
                obj.isChecked = true;
              }
              else {
                obj.isChecked = false;
              }
              }
            });

          }

        }
      }

      getSharedIds(sPk) {
      //  this.dicom.getSharedIDs(sPk).subscribe(res => {
      //    if (res.Body) {
            const inviteeIds = this.res
              ? this.res.split(",")
              : [];
            this.userList.forEach(r => {
              r.isChecked = false;
            //  r.isDisabled = false;
              if (inviteeIds) {
                inviteeIds.forEach(i => {
                  if (i == r.Id) {
                    r.isChecked = true;
                    r.isDisabled = true;
                  }
                });
              }
            });
          }
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elghmx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Change click event to change event on input and add disabled property on each input that will be changed based on the fact that if one checkbox is disabled or not.

HTML

```
 <div *ngFor="let contact of userList" [hidden]="!contact.isDisabled">    
    <input  type="checkbox" name="radio" (change)="selectCheckboxInvitee($event.target.checked, contact, false)" [disabled]="contact.disable" [(ngModel)]="contact.isChecked"  />
    <a>{{ contact.FirstName }} &nbsp;{{ contact.LastName }}</a>
 </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
selectCheckboxInvitee(evt, contact, isMultiple) {
    if (!evt) {
        this.userList.forEach(function (obj) {          
            if (obj.Id !== contact.Id) {
              obj.disable = true;
            } else {
              obj.disable = false;
            }          
        });
    } else {
      this.userList.forEach(function (obj) {          
              obj.disable = false;
        });
    }
  }
```

Also you need to add any type with the userList object     `userList:any ;`

See updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b3ixkt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)